# Swift UIKit name collision

Tags: swift

I needed to change an old project which currently does not compile anymore. I've simplified the code to the following:

```
struct Event {
    let name: String
}

class ChildControl: UIControl {
    func load(event: Event) {
        event.name // <--- error
        // error: Playground.playground:5:9: error: value of type 'UIControl.Event' has no member 'name'
        // event.name
        ^~~~~ ~~~~
    }
}
```

How can I tell swift to use the Event struct that I've declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use module names for namespace purposes, like this: `ModuleName.Event`

**P.S.** If you didn't change it in the Build Settings, name of your module matches name of your target